# Task details don't show a field if another field is present

Tags: lightning-experience, tasks, detail-page

I have created an activity action which is based on a Task target object. 
When clicking on the action and going to the details page, I want the Type field to be hidden.

The logic I am thinking is like this: in task details, don't show Type if Activity Type is not null.

Is that possible?

Please note I don't want to completely remove the Type field from all tasks. Cause there are other type of tasks that have their type field used. My goal is to only remove type field for the action I have created.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a way around for your problem. There is always an option to create custom Lightning Component to achieve your ask, but you can do it using point and click option using **related record standard component** in Lightning App Builder.

Steps to follow:-

> 1. Create two quick actions of type update the record on the Task object. On one action, keep the type field and activity type in
>      another one. Do not include both in same.
> 2. Go to a task record and click edit page. It will take you to Lightning App builder page
> 3. Remove the record detail component from the detail tab
> 4. Insert related record component at the place of record detail component and select the action name which you have created in an update
>      action attribute in Right-hand side
> 5. Similarly, Insert another one just below the just insert related record component and select the appropriate action name in the update
>      action option in the right-hand side of the lightning app builder
> 6. Now, you need to set the component visibility based on your criteria. You will find the option to set component visibility in
>      right below corner of the Lightning App builder page
> 7. You can use the record field and its value to set visibility.

Once done, User will see the component based on your condition and ultimately this is what you want.

Refer below images:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant. The only issue I have is for the filter type having only equal or not equal. Doesn't have null checking. I want to see if activity type is null show one vs the other. Any thoughts?

Comment: @apadana To check null, use equal operator and leave the values as blank.